# Simple file text search tool?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm looking for an open source tool that can be used to search text files on the local machine. I've looked at elasticsearch but it seems too complicated with more features than I need.

I need to search only text files on the local machine. I'm looking for something that'll take as input a directory of files and a search string and will output a list of files that contain the string. Data size will probably be multiple GB spread across hundreds of files so something that has an indexing capability would probably work the best. A simple, client side HTML UI would be fantastic.

I don't need data streaming, collection, multi-server aggregation, web services, multiple file format support, external databases, etc.

Somebody must have already done this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edited to add: I'm looking for a library, something that can be integrated into another client side application. A local front end for lucene/elasticsearch/etc that does not require a web server or database.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search text files in multiple directory. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) could do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Agent Ransack is my favorite -- it will use multiple threads, and it can optionally use regex patterns for your file search.

Answer (score 0):

Though it only works by individually searching each file, the [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) program may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using a text search tool---[TEXT FINDING](http://textfinding.com/) .It is a simple and free tool for you to find all types of files in PC,just a few seconds can be done!